# What is/are the minimum rights required to perform Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, azure-powershell

I would like to assign the rights for mid-level admins to revoke 365 sessions for users in Office 365 (perhaps after accounts become compromised). What are the minimum rights necessary to allow an admin to revoke sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to grant the user `User administrator` role.

> Can manage all aspects of users and groups, including resetting
>   passwords for limited admins.

[image]

You can run `Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken` command in powershell or call [Azure AD graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-for-a-user) directly by using [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/).

The other one is to create an application and grant it 'Directory.ReadWrite.All' permission.

> This will allows the app to read and write data in your organization's
>   directory, such as users, and groups, without a signed-in user. Does
>   not allow user or group deletion.

Both of them include other permissions, not only 'Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken' permission. It depends on you which one include the least permissions for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I'm going to check these options and come back