# I want to revoke the refresh tokens for all users in a group. Can someone please check my work?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

```
Connect-AzureAD

$ObjectID = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please paste the ObjectID of the group here'

Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectID $ObjectID -All $true | select-Object -Property ObjectID | Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken
```

This will connect to Azure then get the ObjectID from the user running the script of the group they want to revoke the tokens of. It will then revoke the token of every member of the group.

Comment: Have you tried `-Whatif`? You may have to take a look at `Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken` to see if it accepts *valuebypropertyname*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by following this
Using Microsoft graph API

```
 POST https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/users/{user_object_id}/invalidateAllRefreshTokens
```

Or, using PowerShell

```
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken  -ObjectId  "{user_object_id}"
```

Please refer below links for further more information:

.[MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0),

. [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773401/what-is-are-the-minimum-rights-required-to-perform-revoke-azureaduserallrefresht) .

.&  [How to Revoke Azure Active Directory Tokens from Expired Users](https://biztechmagazine.com/article/2020/11/how-revoke-azure-active-directory-tokens-expired-users).